# cannot import name 'LangchainEmbedding' from 'llama_index'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, embedding, langchain, llama-index

I'm trying to build a simple RAG, and I'm stuck at this code:

```
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding, ServiceContext

embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(
  HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="thenlper/gte-large")
)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    chunk_size=256,
    llm=llm,
    embed_model=embed_model
)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)
```

where I get ImportError: cannot import name 'LangchainEmbedding' from 'llama_index'
How can I solve? Is it related to the fact that I'm working on Colab?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe check documentation. It seems it doesn't have `from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding` but `from llama_index.embedings import LangchainEmbedding` (See [source code](https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/main/llama_index/embeddings/__index__.py))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not

```
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding
```

but

```
from llama_index.embeddings import LangchainEmbedding
```

(See source code for [llama_index/embeddings/__ init__.py](https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/main/llama_index/embeddings/__init__.py))

Answer (score 3):

Now this is the right Answer, LangchainEmbedding replace with HuggingFaceEmbeddings.
Now its working.

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index import ServiceContext, set_global_service_context

embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
)
```

Comment: The answer needs bettweb formating following the guideline

Answer (score 2):

With reference to above code. This is working exactly.

```
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index import ServiceContext, set_global_service_context

embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
  model_name="thenlper/gte-large"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a problem with

```
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding
```

or

```
from llama_index.embedings import LangchainEmbedding
```

It looks like the syntax has been updated yet again, see:

```
https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/main/llama_index/embeddings/__init__.py
```

As of 2023 Dec 7th, it says:

```
from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
```

Today that works...tomorrow...a brave new world.